# Statistics & Machine learning predict success or failure of actions

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, cross-validation

So currently I have a machine learning type setup with an artificial neural network type of system set up..out of the data query I get when asking for say a specific date and time and the success of something(can't talk about what).

Then I can get a list of this question. Now that I have a list of this data containing the meta data which is labeled as success or failure(this is based on another algorithm deciding this) for a given date how can I predict from this data model if a future event will be most likely. 
Is Linear regression the best option?

Any suggestions would be very helpful :)!

Comment: This question would be better at [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/), as it is seeking statistical advice.

Comment: Will ask there thanks, still new to this sites sub forum etc stuf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linear regression is for predicting real numbers, like a price.

Success/failure is not a real number. You want to use a statistical classifier for this.

You can use a neural network for this.